# Express 24 hours in any Java TimeUnit

Tags: java, timeunit

If my time unit is of type seconds and cycle duration is 20 sec after 86400/20 = 4320 cycles, 24 hours are passed.

```
long numberOfCyclesToReach24Hours(long cycleDuration, TimeUnit unit) {
    // if I knew that unit is of type seconds I could
    return TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(24) / cycleDuration
    // but if it is of type MILLISECONDS for example I have to
    //return TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24) / cycleDuration
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem or I really have to switch case all of the types? I know it would not happen that often, but if in the future new `TimeUnit` type is introduced, the code has to be adapted :)

I was also thinking of something like using the `TimeUnit.values` method and relying on the order of the returned type and by checking the position of the input unit in it to know by which constant (1000L, 60L etc.) I could calculate the number of cycles on my own without any `toSeconds`, `toMillis` etc. methods, but this is even uglier and really strange :)

Comment: Note that the first version of my answer was the wrong way round - I've fixed it now, but if you tried it with `TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(24, unit)` that would give the wrong answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for the [`convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method:

> Converts the given time duration in the given unit to this unit.

```
return unit.convert(24, TimeUnit.HOURS) / cycleDuration;
```

Comment: wow, I was pretty sure I checked all possible methods ot the TimeUnit enum. I guess I need a cup of coffee, thanks :)